# Join without duplicates

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm running this query to get a list of people and pets associated with a household, however the query returns a row equal to the product of the amount of people and pets associated with the household instead of the sum. I'm essentially trying to get 2 queries in 1. Bellow is an example of the test data, observed behaviour and expected behaviour.

```
SELECT * 
FROM households 
LEFT JOIN pets 
  ON households.house_id = pets.house_id 
LEFT JOIN people 
  ON households.house_id = people.house_id 
WHERE households.house_id IN ("5");
```

Tables:

```
HOUSEHOLDS
house_id name
5        foo
6        bar    

PEOPLE
person_id  house_id
333        5
444        5    


PETS
pet_name   house_id
boo        5
bii        5
baa        5    


RESULT (6 rows, 2*3)
house_id name person_id house_id pet_name house_id
5        foo  333       5        boo      5
5        foo  444       5        boo      5
5        foo  333       5        bii      5
5        foo  444       5        bii      5
5        foo  333       5        baa      5
5        foo  444       5        baa      5 

EXPECTED (5 rows, 2+3)
house_id name person_id house_id pet_name house_id
5        foo  NULL      NULL     boo      5
5        foo  NULL      NULL     bii      5
5        foo  NULL      NULL     baa      5
5        foo  333       5        NULL     NULL
5        foo  444       5        NULL     NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you realize `JOIN` is equivalent to multiplication `*`

You need to use `UNION` is equivalent to addition `+`

```
SELECT h.house_id, h.name, 
       p1.person_id, 
       p1.house_id,
       null as pet_name,
       null as house_id
FROM households h
LEFT JOIN people p1
  ON h.house_id = p1.house_id 
WHERE h.house_id IN ("5")

UNION ALL

SELECT h.house_id, h.name, 
       null as person_id, 
       null as house_id,
       p2.pet_name,
       p2.house_id
FROM households h
LEFT JOIN pets p2
  ON h.house_id = p2.house_id 
WHERE h.house_id IN ("5")
```